# Specify ggplot2 labeller options without passing label values

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have a facetted point plot, and the facets are based on multiple factors:

```
p = p + facet_wrap(~ model + run, ncol = 1, scales = 'fixed')
```

I'm happy with ggplot2 using the existing unique values of `model` and `run` to build the facet labels, but I'd like to have them across one line, not multiple. However,

```
p = p + facet_wrap(~ model + run, ncol = 1, scales = 'fixed',
  labeller = label_value(multi_line = FALSE)
```

results in a missing argument error, because `label_value()` [expects the argument `labels` first](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labellers.html):

```
Error in lapply(labels, as.character) :
  argument "labels" is missing, with no default
```

I'm not sure how to supply this given there are multiple facetting variables specified. If I leave the labeller out entirely, ggplot2 seems happy to work it out itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to pass the function without calling it (it will be called with the labels when constructing the plot), so:

```
p = p + facet_wrap(~ model + run, ncol = 1, scales = 'fixed',
  labeller = function(labs) {label_value(labs, multi_line = FALSE)})
```

Comment: Bang. Perfect answer!